# org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException with Pac4j 6.0.1 + jakartaee-pac4j 8.0.0

Tags: pac4j

I am migrating jakartaee-pac4j from 7.1.0 to 8.0.0. Using pac4j-saml 6.0.1, shiro 1.13.0, buji-pac4j 9.0.0 with Java 17 and Payara 6.2024.1 Application Server.

I see this error while deploying the application, not sure what is wrong or what other changes i need to do.

```
  Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:Exception List with 3 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Config with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces org.pac4j.jee.util.Pac4jProducer.getWebContext(Config, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
  at org.pac4j.jee.util.Pac4jProducer.getWebContext(Pac4jProducer.java:0)

Exception 1 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Config with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces org.pac4j.jee.util.Pac4jProducer.getSessionStore(Config, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
  at org.pac4j.jee.util.Pac4jProducer.getSessionStore(Pac4jProducer.java:0)

Exception 2 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Config with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces org.pac4j.jee.util.Pac4jProducer.getProfileManager(Config, WebContext, SessionStore)
  at org.pac4j.jee.util.Pac4jProducer.getProfileManager(Pac4jProducer.java:0)
```

Pleas help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Config` component cannot be found/injected. Do you still have somewhere: `@Produces @ApplicationScoped Config buildConfiguration() {...`?

Comment: No, I have not used it for building configuration. But I have used ApplicationScoped and Produces for my loggers implementation, not related to Pac4j. Is this an issue?and this is how my shiro.ini looks "config = org.pac4j.core.config.Config 
config.clients = $clients". Let me know if  you need more info.

Comment: jlelue, I have got this working with previous version of pac4j, can you please confirm if this is an issue with pac4j or do i need to make some sort of changes. This upgrade is tied with Java 17 and without this fix cannot proceed further. Any help on this matter would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The methods in older version of Pac4jProducer does not have Config as parameter, but the new version has this parameter. Isn't the Config class required to be CDI annotated? The default bean discovery mode for CDI with Jakarta EE 10 is "annotated" (bean-discovery-mode="annotated")

Comment: You're right, `Config` is a new parameter. What do you mean by "Isn't the Config class required to be CDI annotated?"? Can you submit a PR to the project? I'll merge it and you can test with version `8.0.1-SNAPSHOT`...

Comment: I mean we need to make the Config available for CDI. I have made a work around to creata class of ApplicationScoped  that Produces an instance of Config  so that everytime the methods in Pac4jProducer.java is called it creates an instance of Config and this solved the deploymen issue. But would love to see a fix from Pac4j.

Comment: Can you submit a pull request to the project? Thanks